# Why does my Prolog predicate invert/2 not work?

Tags: list, prolog

I'm new to Prolog and as an exercise I want to make an list invertion predicate. It uses the `add_tail` predicate that I made earlier—some parts might be redundant, but I don't care:

```
add_tail(A, [], A) :-
   !.
add_tail([A|[]], H, [A,H]) :-
   !.
add_tail([A|B], H, [A|C]) :- 
   add_tail(B,H,C).
```

It works same as builtin predicate `append/3`:

```
?- add_tail([a,b,c], d, A).
A = [a, b, c, d].

?- append([a,b,c], [d], A).
A = [a, b, c, d].
```

When I use `append` in my `invert` predicate, it works fine, but if I use `add_tail`, it fails:

```
invert([], []).
invert([A|B], C) :- 
   invert(B, D),
   append(D, [A], C).

invert2([], []).
invert2([A|B], C) :- 
   invert2(B, D),
   add_tail(D, A, C).

?- invert([a,b,c,d], A).
A = [d, c, b, a].

?- invert2([a,b,c,d], A).
false.                          % expected answer A = [d,c,b,a], like above
```

What exactly is my mistake? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of `add_tail/3` does *not* quite behave the way you expect it to.
Consider:

```
?- append([], [d], Xs).
Xs = [d].

?- add_tail([], d, Xs).
false.
```

That's bad... But it gets worse! There are even more issues with the code you presented:

- By using `(!)/0` you needlessly limit the versatility of your predicate.
- Even though `[A|[]]` maybe correct, it obfuscates your code. Use `[A]` instead!
- `add_tail` is a bad name for a predicate that works in more than one direction.
- The variable names could be better, too! Why not use more descriptive names like `As`?

  Look again at the variables you used in the last clause of `add_tail/3`!

  ```
  add_tail([A|B], H, [A|C]) :-
     add_tail(B, H, C).
  ```

  Consider the improved variable names:

  ```
  add_tail([A|As], E, [A|Xs]) :-
     add_tail(As, E, Xs).
  ```

---

I suggest starting over like so:

```
list_item_appended([], X, [X]).
list_item_appended([E|Es], X, [E|Xs]) :-
   list_item_appended(Es, X, Xs).
```

Let's put `list_item_appended/3` to use in `list_reverted/2`!

```
list_reverted([], []).
list_reverted([E|Es], Xs) :- 
   list_reverted(Es, Fs),
   list_item_appended(Fs, E, Xs).
```

Sample query:

```
?- list_reverted([a,b,c,d], Xs).
Xs = [d, c, b, a].
```

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to pinpoint your *exact* mistake, but the first two clauses of `add_tail/3`, the ones with the cuts, are wrong (unless I am misunderstanding what the predicate is supposed to do). Already the name is a bit misleading, and you should should care that you have redundant code.

```
list_back([], B, [B]).
list_back([X|Xs], B, [X|Ys]) :-
    list_back(Xs, B, Ys).
```

This is a drop-in replacement for your `add_tail/3` in your definition of `invert/2`. But as you are probably aware, this is not a very clever way of reversing a list. The textbook example of how to do it:

```
list_rev(L, R) :-
    list_rev_1(L, [], R).

list_rev_1([], R, R).
list_rev_1([X|Xs], R0, R) :-
    list_rev_1(Xs, [X|R0], R).
```

Answer (score 1):

First try the most general query, to see which solutions exist in the most general case:

```
?- add_tail(X, Y, Z).
```

yielding the single answer:

```
X = Z,
Y = []
```

That's probably not the relation you intend to define here.

Hint: `!/0` typically destroys all logical properties of your code, including the ability to use your predicates in all directions.

Comment: s(X) for shifting the focus on more general uses.

Answer (score 0):

based on previous answer of "@mat" the problem is residue in the first two lines

your predicate `add_tail` is not like `append` because

with `append` i get this

```
| ?- append(X,Y,Z).
Z = Y,
X = [] ? ;
X = [_A],
Z = [_A|Y] ? ;
X = [_A,_B],
Z = [_A,_B|Y] ? ;
X = [_A,_B,_C],
Z = [_A,_B,_C|Y] ? ;
X = [_A,_B,_C,_D],
Z = [_A,_B,_C,_D|Y] ? ;
X = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E],
Z = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E|Y] ? ;y
```

and unfortunately with ur `add_tail` i get this result

```
| ?- add_tail(X,Y,Z).
Z = X,
Y = [] ? ;
X = [_A],
Z = [_A|Y] ? ;
X = [_A|_B],
Y = [],
Z = [_A|_B] ? ;
X = [_A,_B],
Z = [_A,_B|Y] ? ;
X = [_A,_B|_C],
Y = [],
Z = [_A,_B|_C] ? 
X = [_A,_B,_C],
Z = [_A,_B,_C|Y] ? y
yes
```

after a simple modification in your `add_tail` code i obtained your expected result

**code**

```
%   add_tail(A,[],A):-! . comment

add_tail([],H,H) :-!.
add_tail([A|B],H,[A|C]) :- add_tail(B,H,C).
```

**test `add_tail`**

```
| ?- add_tail(X,Y,Z).

    Z = Y,
    X = [] ? ;
    X = [_A],
    Z = [_A|Y] ? ;
    X = [_A,_B],
    Z = [_A,_B|Y] ? ;
    X = [_A,_B,_C],
    Z = [_A,_B,_C|Y] ? ;
    X = [_A,_B,_C,_D],
    Z = [_A,_B,_C,_D|Y] ? ;
    X = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E],
    Z = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E|Y] ? y
    yes
```

finaly

i test ur  `invert` predicate *without* modification

```
| ?- invert([_A,_B,_C],L).
L = [_C,_B,_A] ? ;
no
```

I hope this post help you to explain how the predicate done  inside

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

The first clause of add_tail/3 has a *list* as second argument, so it will never apply to your test case. Then we are left with 2 clauses (simplified)

```
add_tail([A],H,[A,H]):-!.
add_tail([A|B],H,[A|C]) :- add_tail(B,H,C).
```

You can see that we miss a matching clause for the empty list as first argument. Of course, append/3 instead *has* such match.